# Multiple gutter icons of Related XML files in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

In Android Studio, I just noticed 4 gutter icons of **Related XML file** in Kotlin Activity, even if they are all related to the same layout XML file.

[image]

While in Java Activity there is only one.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: What do the icons say if you hover over them? They should tell you to what they are referring to.

Comment: They refer me to same XML file which is acitvity_main.xml

Comment: Then most likely it is an IDE bug when using Kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Kotlin and Android Studio 2.3 that can be monitored here: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20419

[image: Activity]
[image: Class]

**Update**

This issue has been fixed with the release of Kotlin 1.1.60.

[1.1.60 Changelog](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#1160)

Comment: This is really annoying! I run Android Studio 3.0 (side by side with 2.3) in which the issue is apparently not reproducible (according to the comment on the bug ticket), but would be good to fix it in 2.3 as well since many devs would not migrate to 3.0 immediately even when it's released publicly.